# What will happen in LDA model if the length of document reduce to a single word?

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, topic-models

During the Gibbs sampling, every step it will sample the topic label for a given word in a given doc based on the join probability (excluding the word in the target document): 1) How much the i-th doc likes a particular topic $k$; 2) how much the topic $k$ likes the word $w$. So the joint probability is given by $\frac{n_{ik} + \alpha}{N_i -1 + K\alpha} \times \frac{n_{w,k} + \eta}{\sum_{j} n_{j, k} + V\eta } $, where $N_i$ is the length of the i-th document, $n_{j,k}$ is the count of word $j$ in topic $k$, and $\alpha$ and $\eta$ are the smoothing parameters (e.g. the hyperparameter for prior Dirichlet Distribution.

However, when the length of every document reduced to 1, then the first term in the joint probability is going to be $\frac{\alpha}{K\alpha} = \frac{1}{K}$. Not sure if the output of the model is still valid. The log-likelihood is still convergent over iterations.

Comment: What's the point of using LDA in such a case? LDA is only useful when a document can have multiple topics. A document with one word can only have one topic. In any event, I think (but I'm not sure) that each word in the vocabulary will belong to a unique topic. In addition, the topics will have no meaning - they will (probabilistically) be based on only the starting conditions.

Comment: The main purpose is to clustering words with different topics, not document-topic clustering. So not sure if this approach is valid, but the result looks reasonable (word-topic clustering) which is a bit surprising.

Comment: If all your documents are one word each, there is no way to cluster the words. Essentially, all you have is a list of words with no relationship to each other. I suspect the reason that the resulting topics seem reasonable is that (1) you have a small number of topics; and (2) as a result, you can find a connection between the (essentially random) groupings of words. But in the end, I don't really see how *any* technique will product meaningful results. That being said, I don't know enough about the document set is and what you are trying to do.